# Access restrictions to Google Charts

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, google-visualization

Day after day,...
and after some time of use, Google Charts stops from loading on my ANGULAR project.
For now I'm in development mode and my project it's running in localhost.

My Browser console shows like this:

> angular-google-charts.js:152 GET https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
>   angular-google-charts.js:132 Failed to load the google chart script!
>   core.js:4002 ERROR Failed to load the google chart script!

After this some of my Google services (via Google Visualization API (?)) just stop working, namely Google maps 'till the day after.
I think this have something to do with access restrictions from the Google side but I'm not sure why it happens and more importantly how to solve this.
Any idea here please?

Comment: did you run "npm install angular-google-charts " in it ?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have installed the library with npm

> npm install angular-google-charts

import it to your modules.ts file

```js
import { GoogleChartsModule } from 'angular-google-charts';
 
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    GoogleChartsModule.forRoot(),
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I did it.
And I already tested it WITH and WITHOUT a mapsApiKey.
like this;
    ...
    GoogleChartsModule.forRoot('my-custom-maps-api-key'),
    ...